# Implement Map function using Reduce in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I need to implement the mapping function using `reduce`. 
Requirements:

- The `map` function should apply a `fn` function to every element in `array`.
- `array` should not be mutated

This is my code so far (I'm checking if the array is empty):

```
function map<A, B>(array: A[], fn: (a: A) => B): B[] {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return [];
  } 

}
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The obvious question is why can't you just use `.map()`?

Comment: @phuzi that's the task - using map is forbidden. I need to impement it with reduce :)

Comment: the check is not necessary, if the array is empty it returns empty anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (untested):

```js
const map = <A, B>(array: readonly A[], fn: (a: A) => B): B[] => {
  return array.reduce((all, item) => {
    all.push(fn(item));
    return all;
  }, [] as B[]);
};
```

Comment: @AnnaHarshyna please use `return [...acc, fn(item)]`. Avoid mutation inside reduce

Comment: @captain-yossarian Care to explain? In this particular circumstance, what benefit is there?

Comment: Reduce is more functional approach. It can be used for function composition. In general, nobody expects mutation here.  Btw, I believe it is better to avoid mutation of arguments. But it is only my thoughts. I respect your approach.

Comment: Nobody expects mutation of a variable local to only this function that the function itself creates? I don't understand why that would be problematic.

Comment: Are You open for explanation and arguments or You just want to argue? I'm asking, because if You are FP hater , nobody wins in this discussion

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgOwEMBbCALijmEQEt8BzAGhz0PvIIFdiAjJHAL44cAYwD2+KlE4JkaLLgIkOAcgBSYgBb4VzRWw4AWAEyDh2URKnFOwQsGhoAFDKQV4SRktLvZAbRUiUhUAXQBKVAA+DBZpWQA6IMdvCDMLbBs7BxdZLxUAIURXKHzCfHwkFTCAbnNXZAB6BowkikLOEWhS8qQBEPNxSWAoGmJMwh4AG2Sct1hclN8kAKTQiJRopwU8eN36vTwkwTCBq2GKgHcPORGx2wnp2cQ8gAlOSYBrKrrZKCa8Kg0SaTEpFESEEplCrPKA4S7XP7NGhwKBvT7mBoAKkxLExUAAsiAoMRCHQoGAxHRhsivDQAGbkpBwCTE+4OFGERD0bgQfDAOBeTQQBpwIVQC5AkGDYB0TjQYBiKAAE0VNGp+CgYmAQuQ4IQcHiuNhuExDSAA

Comment: I'm open for an explanation. In this specific case, what benefit is there to reallocate the array <n> times?

Comment: you are right, no benefit in this specific case.